# TypeScript NodeJs mongoose-paginate-v2 Impossible build project

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to setup mongoose-paginate-v2 in my project but there is no way, I'm trying to build my code but I get these three errors.
Did you have any idea why?
Thanks

```
node_modules/@types/mongoose-paginate-v2/index.d.ts:34:21 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CollationOptions'.

34         collation?: CollationOptions | undefined;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/mongoose-paginate-v2/index.d.ts:45:19 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'QueryFindOptions'.    

45         options?: QueryFindOptions | undefined;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/models/book.model.ts:150:10 - error TS2339: Property 'paginate' does not exist on type 'Model<any, any, any>'.

150     this.paginate(query, options, function (err: any, result: any) {
             ~~~~~~~~
```

My Package.json about

```
    "mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.3.9",
    "@types/mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.3.9",
```

Answer (score -2):

Lets assume someone have added dependencies of mongoose in package.json and prefix on version is like "^7.2.4"
It is not causing you any issue or error for now but as time goes and versioning of mongoose changes.
Try to use "~7.2.4" instead of "^7.2.4"

~version “Approximately equivalent to version”, will update you to all future patch versions, without incrementing the minor version. ~1.2.3 will use releases from 1.2.3 to <1.3.0.

^version “Compatible with version”, will update you to all future minor/patch versions, without incrementing the major version. ^2.3.4 will use releases from 2.3.4 to <3.0.0.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).